# Excel Formula Trouble

Tags: excel-formula

I'm a little stuck with a formula. I'm trying to find the opposition for a player for a particular Gameweek and whether the player is playing at Home or Away.

In Sheet 1 I have:

- **Player (A) | Gameweek (B) | Team (C) |        Opposition (D) | Home or Away (E)**
- A |     5    |    Sale  |      ?? | ??
- A      6        Sale        ?? ??
- B      6        Newcastle   ?? ??
- C      6        Harlequins  ?? ??

In Sheet 2 I have:

- **Gameweek | Home Team | Away Team**
- 5  |      Sale  |     Leicester
- 5        Gloucester Bath
- 6        Bath       Sale
- 6        Newcastle  Bristol
- 6        Harlequins Northampton

How do I create a formula to pull the values out of Sheet 2 to complete the values in Sheet 1, Column D and E, "Opposition" and "Home or Away" respectively? I've added what values I'm expecting in both columns in Sheet 1 below in italics.

- **Player Gameweek Team        Opposition Home or Away**
- A      5        Sale        *Leicester    Home*
- A      6        Sale        *Bath         Away*
- B      6        Newcastle   *Bristol      Home*
- C      6        Harlequins  *Northamption Home*

Apologies for the formatting!

Comment: Fix your formatting.  Then Google `VLOOKUP Excel`

Comment: You also may have to concatenate the team and week to use as a unique key in your vlookup

Comment: The formatting is just in the question on stackoverflow not the actual sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in `Sheet 1` is located at `B6:F10` and data in `Sheet 2` is located at `B6:D11` then enter these Formulas Array:

- FormulaArrays are entered pressing* `[Ctrl]` *+* `[Shift]` *+* `[Enter]` *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

Enter in `E7` then copy to `E8:E10`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 2'!$D$7:$D$11,MATCH($C7&$D7,'Sheet 2'!$B$7:$B$11&'Sheet 2'!$C$7:$C$11,0)),
IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 2'!$C$7:$C$11,MATCH($C7&$D7,'Sheet 2'!$B$7:$B$11&'Sheet 2'!$D$7:$D$11,0)),""))
```

Enter in `F7` then copy to `F8:F10`:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C7&$D7,'Sheet 2'!$B$7:$B$11&'Sheet 2'!$C$7:$C$11,0))),"Home",
IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C7&$D7,'Sheet 2'!$B$7:$B$11&'Sheet 2'!$D$7:$D$11,0))),"Away",""))
```